# NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject with a filtering NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView backed by an NSFetchedResultsController that shows items which have been bookmarked by the user. Items can be un-bookmarked from a button within the row, which leads to the problem. After an item is un-bookmarked, it should disappear from the table view because it no longer matches the predicate, but because my row counts per section have been altered by the update, I get a variation of this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) 
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the 
>   number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the 
>   number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Here's my very simple didChangeObject method:

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeObject:(id)anObject
     atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
    newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

[super controller:controller didChangeObject:anObject atIndexPath:indexPath forChangeType:type newIndexPath:newIndexPath];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

Is there some way that I can instruct the NSFetchedResultsController not to sweat the mismatched counts? Or do I need a different approach entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `didChangeObject` delegate method looks very incomplete,
in particular it does not check *which* event occurred (insertion, deletion or update).

You can find a template in the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol
documenation.
The method looks normally similar to this:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}
```

You should also implement the `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:`
 delegate method.

And I do not understand what the

```
[super controller:controller didChangeObject:anObject atIndexPath:indexPath forChangeType:type newIndexPath:newIndexPath];
```

call is for!

Comment: Thanks Martin. The reason that I don't handle all these cases is that `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` is the only type of change triggered in my app.

Comment: The call to super is there because the class where I implement this method is part of a class hierarchy, but I agree it sort of confuses the issue. 

I will update the post to use your more standard code, as the issue still remains.

Comment: @Dane: But if an item is "un-bookmarked" and does not match the predicate anymore, `didChangeObject` will be called with the `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` event. You really should implement the complete delegate method!

Comment: Ah, I see, that is probably the issue!

Comment: That did indeed fix it, except that I'm still getting an error when the final item in the table view is un-bookmarked.

`CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  attempt to delete row 0 from section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update with userInfo (null)`

Comment: @Dane: Have you implemented `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` as well?

Comment: Nope, seems that I need to read the docs around these didChange methods more closely. Thanks again Martin

Comment: You may alternatively use [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath] in case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove which provides a nice move animation

Comment: @BradGoss: I have rolled back your edit because `[tableView begin/endUpdates]` is usually called from the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods `controllerWill/DidChangeContent` and not from within `controller:didChangeContent:...`, compare the sample code in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html. That gives an animation for the complete FRC change set.

Answer (score 2):

Martin R gave the good answer, but he omit one important thing:

If the FetchControllerProtocol wants to refresh a lot of rows at the same time, it would probably crash.

[The Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) give a very clear typical example of the process. It's important to surround your table changes by beginUpdates & endUpdates methods.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

you should also implement the section refresh if you have sections

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps